# Redux state and component property undefined until ajax resolves

Tags: redux, react-redux

My component get some properties via props with the function:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { entities: { keywords } } = state
  const {locale} = state
  return {
    keywords: keywords[locale]
  }
}
```

I got state keywords using ajax, in the same component:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadKeywords()
  }
```

My component gets rendered twice. First, before the ajax resolves, so in my render method I got undefined:

```
render() {
  const { keywords } = this.props.keywords  
  ...
```

Which is the proper way to solve it? I changed `componentDidMount` to `componentWillMount` without success.

Right now, based on the real-world example, I have initialized keywords state with an empty object:

```
function entities(state = { users: {}, repos: {}, keywords: {} }, action) {
  if (action.response && action.response.entities) {
    return merge({}, state, action.response.entities)
  }

  return state
}
```

My reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer as router } from 'react-router-redux'
import merge from 'lodash/merge'
import locale from './modules/locale'
import errorMessage from './modules/error'
import searchText from './modules/searchText'

// Updates an entity cache in response to any action with response.entities.
function entities(state = { users: {}, repos: {}, keywords: {} }, action) {
  if (action.response && action.response.entities) {
    return merge({}, state, action.response.entities)
  }

  return state
}

export default combineReducers({
  locale,
  router,
  searchText,
  errorMessage,
  entities
})
```

My action:

```
import { CALL_API, Schemas } from '../middleware/api'
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty'

export const KEYWORDS_REQUEST = 'KEYWORDS_REQUEST'
export const KEYWORDS_SUCCESS = 'KEYWORDS_SUCCESS'
export const KEYWORDS_FAILURE = 'KEYWORDS_FAILURE'

// Fetches all keywords for pictos
// Relies on the custom API middleware defined in ../middleware/api.js.
function fetchKeywords() {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      types: [ KEYWORDS_REQUEST, KEYWORDS_SUCCESS, KEYWORDS_FAILURE ],
      endpoint: 'users/56deee9a85cd6a05c58af61a',
      schema: Schemas.KEYWORDS
    }
  }
}

// Fetches all keywords for pictograms from our API unless it is cached.
// Relies on Redux Thunk middleware.
export function loadKeywords() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const keywords = getState().entities.keywords
    if (!isEmpty(keywords)) {
      return null
    }
    return dispatch(fetchKeywords())
  }
}
```

All based on the [Real world redux example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world)

**My Solution**

Given initial state to keywords entity. I'm getting json like this through ajax:
{'locale': 'en', 'keywords': ['keyword1', 'keyword2']}
However as I use normalizr with locale as id, for caching results, my initial state is as I describe in the reducer:

```
function entities(state = { users: {}, repos: {}, keywords: { 'en': { 'keywords': [] } } }, action) {
  if (action.response && action.response.entities) {
    return merge({}, state, action.response.entities)
  }

  return state
}
```

What I don't like is the initial if we have several languages, also remembering to modify it if we add another language, for example fr. In this

```
keywords: { 'en': { 'keywords': [] } }
```

should be:

```
keywords: { 'en': { 'keywords': [] }, 'fr': { 'keywords': [] } }
```

Comment: Can you post your reducer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line looks problematic:

```
const { keywords } = this.props.keywords
```

It's the equivalent of:

```
var keywords = this.props.keywords.keywords;
```

I doubt that's what you intended.

Another thing worth checking is `keywords[locale]` in your `mapStateToProps()` which will probably initially resolve to undefined. Make sure your component can handle that, or give it a sensible default.

Comment: That line was intended.  I updated my problem given a sensible default, as you suggest.